# Wikipedia Raabe's test proof doubt on second part

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to understand the second part of the following proof of Raabe's test.

[image]

**Question:**

**1)** How does the author finds out that $(1+\frac{R}{N})...(1+\frac{R}{n})\geqslant cn^R$  ? I understand the derivation before thanks to another thread but I do not see the relation to the $cn^R$. Where does that come from?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$\log\left(\left(1+\frac RN\right)\cdots\left(1+\frac Rn\right)\right)=R\log n+\mathcal O(1),$$ taking exponentials gives $$\left(1+\frac RN\right)\cdots\left(1+\frac Rn\right)=e^{R\log n+\mathcal O(1)}=e^{\mathcal O(1)}\cdot n^R$$ and $\exp(\mathcal O(1))$ is always greater than some constant $c$.

Comment: I have got only a doubt regarding the fact "$\exp(\mathcal O(1))$ is always greater than some constant $c$." Thanks in advance!

Comment: HINT: $\exp$ is positive so $c=-1$ will suffice!

Comment: Are you considering $\mathcal{O}(1)=c$?

Comment: That may not necessarily hold, e.g. $1/x=\mathcal O(1)$ but is not a constant for $x\ge 1$. But $\exp(\mathcal O(1))$ is always non-negative, so if $c$ is negative then the statement is proven.